# Tried to install KDE but it got hanged up

Tags: 14.04, kde

I tried to install KDE on Ubuntu 14.04 using package manager. It worked once when second time I started my system it was not getting on and got hanged up at ubuntu logo. Following is the screenshot at which system got hanged up

[image]

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25258/discussion-on-question-by-charu-tried-to-install-kde-but-it-got-hanged-up).